# How to get average RGB value of Bitmap on Android?

Tags: java, android

I know how to get the RGB values of individual pixels of a bitmap. How can I get the average RGB value for all of the pixels of a bitmap?

Comment: Klaus66 i have one bitmap and i would like to get RGB value from that bitmap. ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);   int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);  for here get RGB value for specified pixel, but i need to get hole, bitmap.Red=?, bitmap.Green=?, bitmap.Blue=?.

Comment: A bitmap is composed of pixels. It doesn't have its own R, G, B or Alpha values! That's why I don't understand the meaning of this question. Maybe, you want the AVERAGE of all the reds, greens and blues from all the pixels?

Comment: Like that, Average of RGB values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think below code for exact answer to you.
Get the Average(Number of pixels)of Red, Green and Blue value for the given bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = someBitmap; //assign your bitmap here
int redColors = 0;
int greenColors = 0;
int blueColors = 0;
int pixelCount = 0;

for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        int c = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
        pixelCount++;
        redColors += Color.red(c);
        greenColors += Color.green(c);
        blueColors += Color.blue(c);
    }
}
// calculate average of bitmap r,g,b values
int red = (redColors/pixelCount);
int green = (greenColors/pixelCount);
int blue = (blueColors/pixelCount);
```

Comment: For very large images, you might need to use `long` for `redColors` and friends to avoid integer overload.

Comment: yes correct Kevin, should be avoid int, while using very large image.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from john sakthi does not work correctly if the `Bitmap` has transparency (PNGs). I modified the answer for correctly getting the red/green/blue averages while accounting for transparent pixels:

```
/**
 * Calculate the average red, green, blue color values of a bitmap
 *
 * @param bitmap
 *            a {@link Bitmap}
 * @return
 */
public static int[] getAverageColorRGB(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    int size = width * height;
    int pixelColor;
    int r, g, b;
    r = g = b = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            if (pixelColor == 0) {
                size--;
                continue;
            }
            r += Color.red(pixelColor);
            g += Color.green(pixelColor);
            b += Color.blue(pixelColor);
        }
    }
    r /= size;
    g /= size;
    b /= size;
    return new int[] {
            r, g, b
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method for this purpose: [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29)

For instance:

```
int[] colors = new int[yourWidth * yourHeight];
Arrays.fill(colors, Color.Black);
Bitmap bitamp = Bitamp.createBitmap(colors, yourWidth, yourHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Check for typo